# Regex with Delimiter consisting of multiple characters (in addition to normal, 1-character long delimiters)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split, delimiter

I am using the following, to split some text at either `.?!:;` and keep the delimiter :

```
var str = 'Hello! Here is a file. It is called beatles.mp3. And so on!';
let arr = str.match(/[^\/.?!:;]+(?:[\/.?!:;]|$)/g);
// output ==> ["Hello!", "Here is a file.", "It is called beatles.", "mp3.", "And so on!"]
```

This is fine, but I'd like to have a way to say (and, just as I do now, keep the delimiter):
"Split everywhere where there is a `.`, but if there is a `.` followed by `mp3`, I'd like you to keep the full `.mp3`. Anywhere else, split where there's a `.`"

Wanted output:

```
["Hello!", "Here is a file.", "It is called beatles.mp3.", "And so on!"]
```

Comment: Please try [`(\. (?!mp3)|! )`](https://regex101.com/r/QVtPMz/2). Feel free to add other punctuations accordingly. Please do let me know if it helped?

Comment: There is space after full stop. Is this common across whole string ?

Comment: @xMayank No, I can't assume this unfortunately :(

Comment: @Mandy8055 this seems to be using the spaces after the `.`? I cannot assume this for the full text.

Comment: Please check this. [`(?:\.(?!mp3)|[!&^?:;/])`](https://regex101.com/r/QVtPMz/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match any char except one of the delimiters including not matching the dot.

When do matching a dot, check if what is on the right is not `mp3`. If that is the case, you can match the dot.

Repeat that process until you encounter one of the delimiters `.?!:;\/`

```
([^.?!:;\/]+(?:\.(?=mp3\b)[^.?!:;\/]*)*[.?!:;\/]) ?
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^.?!:;\/]+` Match 1+ times any char except the listed
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\.(?=mp3\b)` Match `.` and assert what is directly to the right is not `mp3`
    - `[^.?!:;\/]*` Match 0+ times any char except the listed
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times
  - `[.?!:;\/]` Match one of the listed
- `) ?` Close group 1 and match an optional space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3kGeFS/1)

The value is in capturing group 1 `m[1]` in the example code.

```js
const regex = /([^.?!:;\/]+(?:\.(?=mp3\b)[^.?!:;\/]*)*[.?!:;\/]) ?/g;
const str = `Hello! Here is a file. It is called beatles.mp3. And so on!`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) console.log(m[1]);
```

Comment: this is so amazing, helping me out A LOT. thank you so much, i picked your answer. thanks also for the detailed explanation. i have so many regex questions still, can you recommend a good resource? I'm really impressed, thanks again!

Comment: @userjmillohara You are welcome. These sites contain a lot of information https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and  https://www.rexegg.com/ SO itself also contains pages with very nice answers and explanations, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5424988

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
((?:\.(?!mp3)|[!&^?:;/]))
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(?:\.(?!mp3)`** - Represents a non-capturing group not matching a `.` if it is preceded by `mp3`.
- **`|`** - Represents alternation.
- **`[!&^?:;/]`** - Represents punctuation where split may happen. You can add other punctuation too.
- **`$1\n`** - For the replacement part use the captured group followed by a new-line. Finally split the result string and remove the trailing  following spaces which occur.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/KROBYi/1)

```js
/*
const regex = /(?:\. (?!mp3)|[!&^?:;/] ?)/g;
const str = `Hello! Here is a file. It is called beatles.mp3. And so on!`;
console.log(str.split(regex).filter(el => el));
*/
const regex = /((?:\.(?!mp3)|[!&^?:;/]))/gm;
const str = `Hello! Here is a file. It is called beatles.mp3. And so on!`;
const subst = `$1\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

result.split("\n").forEach(el => console.log(el.trim()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```js
const str = 'Hello! Here is a file. It is called beatles.mp3. And so on!';
const arr = str.match(/[^ ].+?(\.(?!mp3)|[\/?!:;])/g);
```

Output:

```js
["Hello!", "Here is a file.", "It is called beatles.mp3.", "And so on!"]
```